# How to Expand Horizontal Barchart Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

How can I expand the barh so that when I save this horizontal bar chart as an image the 200 categories in the Y-axis are displayed properly not overlapping one another.

[image]

I would like the image to look like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FonfR.jpg

Code

```
[x, y] =xlsread('MyStocks.csv');

x = x(1:end, 4); %Get X Values
y = y(2:end, 1); %Get Y labels
barh(x);
set(gca, 'YTickLabel',y, 'YTick',1:numel(y));
set(gca,'YLim',[1 length(x)]);
```

Comment: Please add a snippet of code that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The figure size should be expanded vertically.  It will probably have to go way off your screen, so you can set the figure size programmatically with `set(gcf,'Position',[x y w h])`.  Just play with `h` and save the figure when it looks the way you want.

Comment: I tried this but it is only expanding the height of the figure not the actual plot area.